# EM for mixture of negative binomial distributions in R

Tags: optimization, negative-binomial-distribution, expectation-maximization

I'm having problems with a fairly basic EM algorithm for a mixture of negative binomial distributions. Given the mean-dispersion parametrisation of the negative binomial distribution,  we have a model of the form

$$ y_n | \pi_n = c \sim \mathcal{NB}(\mu = m \lambda_c, \phi) $$

for $n = 1, \ldots, N$, where $\pi_n$ signifies which cluster ($c$) sample $n$ comes from. In other words, the mean of $y$ is a global mean $m$ times a component specific mean $\lambda_c$, where $\lambda$ is known.

The basic EM algorithm proceeds as:

1. E-step: compute $\gamma_{nc} = p(\pi_n = c | \cdot) = \frac{\mathcal{NB}(y_n | m \lambda_c)}{\sum_{c'} \mathcal{NB}(y_n | m \lambda_{c'})}$
2. M-step: Maximise $Q(\theta|\theta^{(t-1)}) = \sum_n \sum_c \gamma_{nc} \log \mathcal{NB}(y_n | m \lambda_c, \phi)$ wrt $(m, \phi)$

Because no closed form MLE of a negative binomial exists, I've been using L-BFGS-B optimisation using `optim` in `R`. However, when I do this the $Q$ function does not increase at every iteration - there's a big jump at the first iteration, then it slowly decreases (though converges to a value fast).

Is there anything obviously wrong with this scheme?

Comment: The package `countreg` on R-Forge (https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=522) also provides a plugin for the `flexmix` package to estimate a negative binomial finite mixture model. See `help("FLXMRnegbin", package = "countreg")` for a detailed worked example from the supplements of Kleiber & Zeileis (2016, The American Statistician, https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2016.1173590).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days thinking about this, the answer is - $Q$ function shouldn't increase at every iteration, but the (log) marginal likelihood, which in this case is given by

$$ \log p(Y, \lambda) = \sum_n \log\left[ \sum_c \mathcal{NB} (y_{n} | m \lambda_c, \phi) \right]. $$

Comment: Can you post the code for your solution as well? I'm struggling with a similar problem

Comment: Preprint describing the model now online at - https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/06/11/344309